Problem in locating and stopping radiation from an ethernet phy and RMII signaling
An FCC unintentional radiators test is failing at 550MHz, after probing with a near field probe the source was located to these areas of the PCB (shown below in black circles). The RMII is running at 25MHz, so that would be the 20th harmonic. Ther are three sources of possible noise. Rise times from digital signaling, or conducted emissions from other areas of the processor. Or (one that is less likely) the PHY (KSZ8051RNLU)itself. The other option is there is some kind of conducted emissions from the processor.
The series resistors for the RMII have also been changed from 22Ω to 33Ω, with no reduction in the near field emissions. If I increase the impedance and the near field emissions do not change, then rise times should be affected, due to the RC time constant being increased. Is that a true statement?
It was my belief that after the 10th harmonic of rise times, radiation would pretty much be dead due to roll off is that true?
I also changed the power with a resistor instead of a ferrite as suggested.
EDIT:
Interestingly enough we have matched the drive strength and gone from 22Ω to 50Ω with no reduction in the near field radiation.




Have you got a continual ground plane under the resistors?

Are the RMII series resistors on PHY side for both inputs and outputs - should the resistors always be on outputa? Also the schematic appears to have same net names on both sides of resistors, so are the resistors bypassed so changing them has no effect?

@Justme Yes, inputs and outputs. The name is actually different so they aren't being bypassed. There is another name in front that I had to remove so it wasn't identifying the CPU we are using.

@VoltageSpike OK, resistors are inline, but are they physically located right at the transmit pins on each chip, instead of just placed near one chip, so the resistors at chip inputs are not really doing impedance matching?

@Justme Do I need to impedance match for 25MHz? Also my understanding was that the resistors only need to be on one side of the interface to slow down the rise times.

@VoltageSpike A source termination resistor is a bit useless if it is not at the signal source. So half of them should be near CPU outputs and half on PHY outputs. 100 Mbps RMII should run at 50 MHz clock, and thus data lines have maximum frequency of 25 MHz. The CMOS output needs to drive the bus impedance and capacitance, and too strong driver consumes current if it toggles with fast slew, to which the resistor at output would help. Or software controlled drive strength.

Are you sure the ethernet cable is the radiating culprit? Are there any other cables in the system? Does a shielded ethernet cable solve the problem?

How does the ground plane look like?

@Chupacabras It's a 6 layer board with grounds under both the top layer and bottom layer. Most of the signalling runs on the bottom layer.

I also found out that we can change the drive strength on the MCU, so I'll try that.

When you signal trace goes from layer 1 to 6, do you have also adjacent ground via?

"It was my belief that after the 10th harmonic of rise times, radiation would pretty much be dead" -- Aside from what sense to make of "harmonic of rise times" (I would assume: take the risetime as approx. 1/2 cycle of a sine wave, and then take the 10th harmonic of that frequency), what is the rise time anyway?  Have you measured it, do you have a scope fast enough to resolve it (potentially 1GHz+)?

@TimWilliams I have measured it, I have a 1GHz scope, and it shows up. Funny thing is changing the drive strength from 25Ω to 50Ω doesn't help.

@Chupacabras I have one 80mil ~2mm away.

@Justme The processor has the ability to switch from 22Ω 33Ω or 50Ω with drive strength. I have tried 22Ω and 50Ω matched on both ends with no reduction in the harmonic. Reducing the drive strength should reduce the rise time and also harmonic?

@VoltageSpike Yes well some CPUs have separate slew control (as in limiting the speed) and strength control (limiting the current). BTW, 550 MHz is 11x 50 MHz RMII clock so it may be the buses or supply of PHY.

The drive strength of the RMII pins on the CPU and the series resistors were changed to 50Ω. Even changing just the CPU drive strength to 50Ω to reduce rise times cut the near field emissions and also passed FCC unintentional radiators.
